# Javascript count repeating letter

Tags: javascript, algorithm, repeat

I'm new student in here,sorry for asking simple question and I'm trying to solve a problem to count a same letter.

```
Input:"aabbcde"
cause a = 2, b= 2, c= 1 , d =1 , e = 1
Output:"2a2b1c1d1e" or a2b2c1d1e1
```

and here's my code unfinished, I stucked

```
function repeatL(str) {
    var word = str.split("").sort();
    var temp = 0;
    var i =1;
    while(i< word.length){
        if(word[i] === word[i +1]) { 
            //return temp to array of a += 1 ?
        };
    }
}
repeatL("abbbdd"); //output should be a1b3d2
```

also what if the input is not string but an array:

```
Input:[a,ab,bc,d,e]
```

is that even possible to solved?

Comment: What is the expected output for this `aabbcdeaaabbeedd`??

Comment: a = 5, b = 4 ,c =1 ,e =3 ,d =2...so >>  a5b4c1e3d2 , sort first for easy count right ?

Comment: Maybe you convert arr to  string like arr.join().replace(/,/g,"") an than run your code against it. And what exactly is your question about?

Comment: if(Array.isArray(obj)) obj = obj.join('');

Comment: _is that even possible to solved?_ now you know nothing is impossible ;p

Comment: The first comment of gkb is really important. The algorithme for the output 2a2b1c1d1e3a2b2e2d is not the same as 5a4b1c3d3e

Comment: @Fefux - yes, but the question asks for the latter one as replied to my comment..

Comment: Oh sorry... I didn't see... My apologize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a variable for the result string, start with a count variable with 1 and iterate with a check of the former and actual letter. Then either count or move the count to the result set with the last letter. Reset counter to one, because the actual letter count is one.

At the end, finish the result with the last count and the letter, because one letter is not processed with the count (remember, you start with index 1, and you look always to the letter before of the actual index).

```js
function repeatL(str) {
    var word = str.split("").sort(),
        count = 1,
        i = 1,
        result = '';

    while (i < word.length) {
        if (word[i - 1] === word[i]) {
            count++;
        } else {
            result += count + word[i - 1];
            count = 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    result += count + word[i - 1];
    return result;
}

console.log(repeatL("aabbcde"));
console.log(repeatL(['a', 'ab', 'bc', 'd', 'e'].join(''))); // with array after joining
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `reduce()` to build array and then `join()` to get string.

```js
var input = "aabbcde";

var result = input.split('').reduce(function(r, e) {
  var i = r.indexOf(e);
  (i != -1) ? r[i - 1] ++: r.push(1, e)
  return r;
}, []).join('')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with an object and add each character as a key. If the key exists increment the value, else add a new key and with value 1

```
function repeatL(str) {
  var count = {};
  var arr = str.split("");
    str = "";
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(count[arr[i]]){
      count[arr[i]] = count[arr[i]]+1;
    }
    else {
       count[arr[i]] = 1;
    }
  }
  for(var key in count){
    str+= key+count[key];
  }
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following example also works with arrays:

```js
function getFrequency(string) {
    var freq = {};
    for (var i=0; i<string.length;i++) {
        var character = string[i];
        if (freq[character]) {
          freq[character]++;
        } else {
          freq[character] = 1;
        }
    }

    return freq;
};

function repeatL(str) {
    var freq = getFrequency(str);
    result = '';
    for (var k in freq) {
        if (freq.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
          result += freq[k] + k;
        }
    }
    return result;
};

console.log(repeatL('abbbdd'));
console.log(repeatL('aabbcdeaaabbeedd'));
console.log(repeatL(['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c']));
```